# Change size of text on label by Tkinter

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I am using Tkinter v2.x on Windows bit-64.

My question is, how to change the size of the text on the `Label` widget?

For example:

```
label = tk.Label( root, text="PASS", bg="green", fg="black", font=2, height=50, width = 50)
```

I did a bunch of research and followed this [tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_label.htm), and I noticed that no matter how I modify the "font, height or width", the label could be enlarged or shrunk but the size of text on the `Label` could not be changed.

Answer (score 10):

The `font` argument takes a tuple with up to 3 members `(family, size, style)`  You can omit the family and simply change the size like this:

```
label = Label(root, text="PASS", bg="green", fg="black", font=(None, 15), height=50, width=50)
```

The `height` and `width` arguments are changing the size of the label itself, they do not affect the font.

Comment: Is it possible to specify the size without specifying the font type?

Comment: @zondo Yes you can pass an empty string as the first element of the tuple `font=('', 12)`

Comment: Ah, I thought there would be a way.  As that is all the OP wanted, I suggest putting that in your answer.

Comment: Thanks Jkdc, it works! Just wondering, is there a way to layout widgets? So far, the only layout I know is to line up all the widgets in one column. Is there a way to make a multi-row and multi-column layout?

Comment: @Amber.G See [here for the grid layout manager](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm)